# Reading File into Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, initialization, java.util.scanner

I am practicing java, and looking at exercises online:

However, I am stuck at the point in which I need to

```
Read the file again, and initialise the elements of the array
```

**Task**

> - Write class Members representing a list of members as an array
> - Constructor should take String argument (file name)
> - Use scanner to read lines and create array big enough to hold the file
> - Read the file again and initialise elements of the array

**Current Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Members {

    MemberElement[] members;

    public Members(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        int numOfLines = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            scan.nextLine();
            numOfLines++;
        }
        scan.close();
        scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        members = new MemberElement[numOfLines];   
}
```

**MemberElement Class**:

```
class MemberElement {

    private String name;
    private int number;
    private int birthDate;

    public MemberElement(String name, int number, int birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public int getBirth() {
        return this.birthDate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " " + getNumber() + " " + getBirth(); 
    }
}
```

Contents Of Text File:

```
Wendy Miller 7654 17-2-1960
Dolly Sheep 4129 15-5-1954
Dolly Sheep 5132 21-12-1981
Irma Retired Programmer 345 15-11-1946
```

Comment: They ask you to read a file twice? Hmm

Comment: Yes, First time to read the number of lines and then close the scanner. Then Open the scanner again to initalise the array

Comment: Okay, where's your concrete problem? Opening the file a second time, or is it reading the lines into the array?

Comment: @fxnn - Reading the lines of the text file into the array

Comment: @RandomMath yes, I understand and is easy to implement as *fxnn* suggested, but I suppose they teach you a bad design (because you may perform full initialization reading the file once).

Comment: Ah sorry, I overlooked that you already opened the scanner for a second time. :)

Comment: write for loop to go from i= 0 to i < numOfLines and initialise element I of the array

Comment: @RandomMath , What's the contents of the file? You need to extract name,number and birthDate from it. Without seeing the contents, we can only guess.

Comment: @CoolGuy - Added above :)

Comment: how is the birthdate in text file is converted to a int..?

Answer (score 4):

It's basically the same like counting lines:

```java
int numOfLines = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    scan.nextLine();
    numOfLines++;
}
```

However, we now need to actually *access* that next line. A quick look into the [Scanner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) tells me, that `nextLine` returns exactly what we want.

```
int numOfLine = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    members[numOfLine] = new MemberElement(line, numOfLine, /* birthDate */);
    numOfLine++;
}
```

Comment: I have just added the members class above

Comment: Okay, I added the `numOfLine` argument. Guess parsing the `birthDate` is the next step of your task :)

Comment: @fxnn , `numofLine` isn't the right thing to pass. The OP has added the contents of the file in the question.

Comment: Huh, I feel like this goes beyond the scope of the OP's original question to read a file into an array.

Answer (score 2):

It says initialise elements of the array. So that would be

```
int index = 0;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    // I assume MemberElement c-tor uses the read data somehow
    // otherwise what's the point in reading the file
    members[index++] = new MemberElement(scan.nextLine());
}

scan.close();
```

Although the task itself does seem to be somewhat strange.

Comment: I have just added the members class above

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Members {

    MemberElement[] members;

    public Members(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        int numOfLines = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            scan.nextLine();
            numOfLines++;
        }
        System.out.println("Lines-->"+numOfLines);
        scan.close();

        members = new MemberElement[numOfLines];
        scan = new Scanner(myFile);
        numOfLines = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String data[]=scan.nextLine().split(",");
            members[numOfLines]=new MemberElement(data[0], data[1], data[2]);
            System.out.println(members[numOfLines]);
            numOfLines++;
        }
    }
}
public class Test2{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     new Members("e:/temp.txt");
    }
}
```

MemberElement.java

```
class MemberElement {

    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String birthDate;

    public MemberElement(String name, String number, String birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public String getBirth() {
        return this.birthDate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " " + getNumber() + " " + getBirth(); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Lines-->4
Wendy Miller  7654  17-2-1960
Dolly Sheep  4129  15-5-1954
Dolly Sheep  5132  21-12-1981
Irma Retired Programmer  345  15-11-1946
```

Comment: Nice, but how to remove the extra space in front of name and number?

Comment: @CoolGuy just trim that extra space by calling `trim()` method

Comment: just do `new MemberElement(data[0].trim(), data[1].trim(), data[2].trim())`

Answer (score 0):

Use a list instead and convert it back to array if you want:

```
public Members(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File myFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
    List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();

    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(scan.nextLine());
    }
    scan.close();
    scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    members = list.toArray();
```

Comment: For explaination: the `ArrayList` shown here implements a self-growing array, so in the end you don't have to count the lines in the beginning, but can rely on the array growing as you need it.