# Error trying to make have an automated type of array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a code that reads a text file, and stores every line into an Array, heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class JavaPractice
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/textFile.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    int x = 1;
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        fileScanner.nextLine();
        x++;
    }
    String names[] = new String[x];
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
    while (reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        names[x] = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(names[x]);
        x--;
    }
    System.out.println(names[0]);


    fileScanner.close();
    reader.close();
}
}
```

What i'm going for is to get fileScanner to read how many lines my file has, store that into X, and then make an array with X number of values, and then start storing my values into the array.

Comment: What is the error? in which line?

Comment: It says in line 7, but thats just the start of my main meothod, its weird.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you want the lines to appear backward in the array? Can you not use ArrayList?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading File into Array - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139837/reading-file-into-array-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your array declaration and the way you access array in while loop,

```
    String names[] = new String[x];
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
    while (reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        names[x] = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(names[x]);
        x--;
    }
```

You are declaring array of size x,

```
String names[] = new String[x];
```

and in while loop you are accessing like this,

```
names[x] = reader.nextLine();
```

Which will run into ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, as you can only access from 0 to x-1 elements in an array,

You should try making it this,

```
names[x-1] = reader.nextLine();
System.out.println(names[x-1]);
```

Also, you should declare your x = 0 instead of x = 1; So your lines are counted correctly.

Comment: I got the same error. I just added the -1 to reader.NextLine() and i got the same error, also made x = 0, still the same error, except my exception error says : 6 instead of : 7

Comment: Using predecrement would be fine.

Comment: Like I added in my answer, you should declare x = 0 instead of x = 1 and you don't need to print System.out.println(names[0]); after your while loop. Just make these corrections and you will be good. Also make x-1 in your print statement too, System.out.println(names[x-1]);